# Designing interface for tree-like structure

Tags: c#, interface, tree

Lets say I have two classes which both have properties related to tree structure: they have a parent node and child nodes of the same type.

```
public class FooNode
{
    FooNode ParentNode { get; set; }
    ICollection<FooNode> ChildNodes { get; set; }
    /* ... */
}

public class BarNode
{
    BarNode ParentNode { get; set; }
    ICollection<BarNode> ChildNodes { get; set; }
    /* ... */
}
```

I would like to design an interface, which would describe the structure. I came up with this:

```
public interface ITreeNode
{
    ITreeValue ParentNode { get; set; }
    ICollection<ITreeValue> ChildNodes { get; set; }
}
```

However to implement the interface, the `ParentNode` and `ChildNodes` have to refer to the `ITreeNode` type instead of the implementation. Thus I cannot have:

```
public class FooNode : ITreeNode
{
    FooNode ParentNode { get; set; }
    ICollection<FooNode> ChildNodes { get; set; }
    /* ... */
}
```

The interface forces me to do this:

```
public class FooNode : ITreeNode
{
    ITreeNode ParentNode { get; set; }
    ICollection<ITreeNode> ChildNodes { get; set; }
    /* ... */
}
```

Which I don't want since I lose the contract that the parent and child nodes are of the same type as the node.

How should I solve this issue? How to design and implement an interface for generic tree nodes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use generics:

```
public interface ITreeNode<T> where T : ITreeNode<T>
{
    T ParentNode { get; set; }
    ICollection<T> ChildNodes { get; set; }
}

public class FooNode : ITreeNode<FooNode>
{
    public FooNode ParentNode { get; set; }
    public ICollection<FooNode> ChildNodes { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Trivial, I should have thought of that. Thank you :)